# How to create a section in ELF?

Tags: c++, c, linux, x86, elf

I'm reading about ELF file format and trying to create one without any library, to really understand how the things works. In fact, I was able to create one by setting all needed headers and put some op code to it print a string on std out. But how to create the string table and then the sections, to be honest, I have no code to show because I didn't understand even how to create the string table myself and set it to `sh_name`. I'd love any code example how to do this. I've search a lot on internet without luck. Even [libelf](http://people.freebsd.org/~jkoshy/download/libelf--/article.html) doesn't show how to do it directly the explanation actually I get it's same as from standard elf document. I've tagged C and C++ but if you know how to do this in any other language please feel free to answer.

Comment: that is a fun project, good luck.

Comment: @jkoshy: Are you the author of this library? I'm going to check out this

Comment: What happend with the comment recomending to I read the library source code?

Comment: (repost) @TheMask You could read the source code for an open-source implementation of libelf to see how it is done:  for example, [BSD libelf](http://sourceforge.net/p/elftoolchain/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/libelf/), [GNU libelf](http://www.mr511.de/software/english.html) or [Open Solaris' libelf](https://hg.openindiana.org/upstream/illumos/illumos-gate/file/74a59768760e/usr/src/cmd/sgs/libelf).